# modify Idea vm memory option on my OSx system didn't change anything

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jvm

I am trying to increase the my idea IDE startup memory. So I:
    right click on Intellij IDEA > show package content > Contents > bin > idea.vmoptions

and the `idea.vmoptions` is modified as:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Xverify:none

-XX:ErrorFile=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea_%p.log
-XX:HeapDumpPath=$USER_HOME/java_error_in_idea.hprof
-Xbootclasspath/a:../lib/boot.jar
```

But it changed nothing.I see the idea process parameter ,it is still `-Xmx768m`,instead of what I have configured `-Xmx2048m`:

/`Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -d64 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==2017.2.5 -Xmx768m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.9 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntelliJ ....`

Also,I copy `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/idea.vmoptions` to `/Users/wuchang/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2017.2/idea.vmoptions`，also doesn't help.

Anyone could give me some suggestions?

My Idea version is `2017.2.5` and mac os version is `10.12.6`.I have also tried to use `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options` to modify it ,also doesn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by "changed nothing"? What change do you expect? What error do you get when running IntelliJ IDEA in the Terminal using `/Applications/IntelliJ\ IDEA.app/Contents/MacOS/idea` command?

Comment: The poster means that the java process in MacOS is not showing their new VM options (as on my system):

`ohernandez$ ps -ax | grep java
 5878 ??         0:04.44 /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -d64 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Didea.version==2018.1.6 -Xmx768m -Didea.maven.embedder.version=3.3.9 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8<snip>`

Comment: @OliverHernandez the issue is that there is another process started for Maven importing and its heap size is [configured elsewhere](https://i.imgur.com/4OFypia.png). The poster is checking the heap size of the Maven importer process instead of IntelliJ IDEA process.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that there is another process started for Maven importing and its heap size is [configured elsewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssl81.png). You are checking the heap size of the **Maven importer** process instead of **IntelliJ IDEA** process.

Comment: Hello,I chaned the configuration with Help -> Edit Custom VM Options and changed to -Xmx2048， but the idea process is still -Xmx768m.

Comment: The idea.vmoptions file posted in the question shows -Xms.  I'm experiencing the same issue where the VM options do not seem to be passed to the startup of the java process on MacOS.

Comment: @OliverHernandez Your issue is unrelated, I've edited the answer to outline what was the real issue for wuchang.

Comment: That is indeed what was happening, thanks for clarifying.  Instead of grepping on 'java', when I grep on 'IntelliJ', I see the actual IDEA process with my custom heap size: `4237 ??         0:12.24 /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -Xmx2048m`